How can i understand what is running IronPython or Python?
With what command inside code can I understand that IronPython or Python is running?

Check the value of platform.python_implementation().

platform.python_implementation()
Returns a string identifying the Python implementation. Possible return values are: ‘CPython’, ‘IronPython’, ‘Jython’, ‘PyPy’.

